Is it possible to customize the Existing User Linking page for an auth provider in a community?
Community users that are linking their user accounts with an auth provider, using the "Existing User Linking URL" given for a community, are shown this standard page:
URL <community_domain>/_ui/identity/sso/ui/LinkAuthorizationPage?...

Can this be customized in any way? The salesforce logo especially is not something to show customers to partners.

No, you'd have to roll your own (the entire authz/linking process) if you want your own linking page.
